# Undefined method `event_id_select' - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo que crear un DropDown dependiendo de los datos de una tabla en mi base de datos, tengo una linea de codigo que creo que puede hacerlo pero tengo un error `Undefined method` de `event_id_select` donde lo puedo declarar o como puedo resoverlo, soy nuevo progrmando en Ruby on rails.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:event_id_select, Event.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event_id_select` no es un atributo en tu modelo, debes utilizar el atributo/columna correcto, el cual debería ser (si seguiste los estándares de *Rails*) `event_id`:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:event_id, Event.all, :id, :name) %>
```